# Modify context path ThingsBoard

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, thingsboard

In a Spring Boot application, I can modify the context path using the property `server.servlet.context-path` in `application.properties`.

Since ThingsBoard uses Spring, I expect a similar customization to be possible.

I want a dockerized ThingsBoard to be under `http://IP_ADDR/thingsboard` instead of the default `http://IP_ADDR:9090`.
As for the port, I can redirect the request on the port `80` with a reverse proxy. My problem is the path `/thingsboard`.

Is there an environment variable that I can use to customize the context path for a ThingsBoard Docker container?

Thanks.

Comment: Any update in this?
I tried modifying ``/usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.yml``

```
<   # Server Context Path
<   servlet:
<     context-path: "/thingsboard"

<     "[/thingsboard/api/**]":
---
>     "[/api/**]":
```

But no luck...

Comment: Unfortunately not, I didn't solve the issue...

Comment: This is not possible to achieve without code change. You should reconfigure many things to do this.

Comment: Thank you. In the end, we (it's not only me) decided that ThingsBoard should be under the `/` path. This way it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to modify the configuration of the Web Server, say Tomcat, which is holding the thingsboard app.

Comment: Can you provide more details about this, please?